# IndexError: list index out of range error while updating empty python dictionary

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, indexing

I am not able to update the empty dictionary with keys from list `l2` and values from list `l1` of same index position, wherever the wanted keys are not found in the dictionary. I'm getting an IndexError again and again.

```
l1=[56,87,12,32]

l2=['a','gf','lk','po',56]
dict={}

print "length of l2 is",len(l2)

print "items",dict.items()

for i in range( len(l2)):

    if l2[i] in (dict.keys()): 

        print 'key is present '

    else:

        print 'key ' ,l2[i],' not present'

        dict[l2[i]]=l1[i]

print dict
```

Comment: aside: avoid using python `built-in` datatypes as variable names: `dict` vs. [dict](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Answer (score 0):

Your last for loop iteration value is 4 (i = 4), and l1's highest index is 3 (4 items in the list, we start the index at 0). So when your for loop runs l1[4] your gonna get a index out of range error, because l1's index only goes up to 3. You either have to add an extra element to l1 or change your for loop.

p.s. Try not to use l's next to numbers in your variables because they tend to look like the number 1.